# Hiding radio button list items based on selection of a item in other radiobutton list using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In my scenario I have 2 radio button lists(asp.net server controls).
If I select an item in my 1st radio button list then two items in the 2nd radio button list should not be visible.

Comment: It will be better if you show some html/asp code excerpts...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#<%# firstRadioBtnList.ClientID %> input[type=radio]").click(function(){
    var secondRadios = $("#<%# secondRadioBtnList.ClientID input[type=radio]");
    // now select which radio buttons you need to hide (from the secondRadios)
    // say those are 'radiosToBeHid'
    radiosToBeHid.closest('td').css('display','none');
});
```